# Fastest way to transfer folders of +/- 300GB between a desktop and a laptop

Tags: file-transfer, data-transfer

I'm buying a pretty beefy laptop and I was wondering whether or not I could carry over video files from my desktop to the laptop and render videos on that to take the load off of the desktop. Since these would be folders with raw video footage they are going to be around 300GB in size. I was wondering what the fastest way to do this would be; eSata?

Answer (score 1):

ESATA is probably a good solution - you have not advised what kind of disks you are using, but if they are SATA disks then that makes the most sense as presumably you are not going to get faster then using the raw interface the disks use - which effectively is what ESATA is.

Otherwise USB3.0 is a good choice.